# Table of 2x2 tikzpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, captions, multicol, minipage

I'm attempting to condense 4 tikzpictures into a smaller space in my document.  The solution I have is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=4in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

Examples

\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5, yscale=.5]
\draw [<->,thick] (0,5) |- (5,0);
\draw [thick] (4,1) --(4,4) node [right] {$A$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.};
\draw [thick, dashed] (4,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,4) -- (4,4);
\draw [fill] (4,1) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw [fill] (4,4) circle [radius=0.1];
\node at (2.5,2.5) {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5, yscale=.5]
\draw [<->,thick] (0,5) |- (5,0);
\draw [thick, dashed] (1,1) to [out=90, in=280] (1,4) to [out=30, in=150] (2,3.5) to [out=30, in=200] (4,4) to [out=40, in=90] (5,3) to [out=270, in=90] node [right] {$A$ is open.} (4,1) to [out=180, in=30] (1,1);
\node at (2.5,2.5) {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5, yscale=.5]
\draw [<->,thick] (0,5) |- (5,0);
\draw [fill] (4,1) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw [fill] (2,1) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw [fill] (3,5) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw [fill] (1,3) circle [radius=0.1];
\node at (5,3) {$A$ is not open.};
\end{tikzpicture}

$\newline$

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5, yscale=.5]
\draw [<->,thick] (0,2) |- (5,0);
\draw [ultra thick] (1,0) --(3,0) node [above] {$A$};
\node at (7,-1) {$A$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ but open in $\mathbb{R}$.};
\draw [fill=white] (1,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw [fill=white] (3,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: My (ugly) solution to condensing 4 tikzpictures.]

The solution involves creating columns and placing the tikzpictures within the columns and forcing them to separate with a \newline.

But this is, in my opinion, an ugly solution.  I'd like to be able to place the 4 tikzpictures in a 2x2 grid, each tikzpicture horizontally and vertically centered within it's cell plus turning each node that currently acts as a label (e.g. "A is open.") into a caption for that tikzpicture.

I tried to do this before by placing each tikzpicture within a minipage, but then this can't be captioned (something about float and absolute figures?), also I tried putting \figures of minipages of tikzpictures which, obviously, didn't work and became messy quickly.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: Put each of your drawings in a scope and use them in one TikZ picture. You can use `[shift={(x,y)}]` option to position the scopes relative to the others. Or use `subcaption` package which is quite handy.

Comment: You're right, using shift is a possible solution.  But I'd prefer one in which the placement of figures is determined by the document's compilation (and tikzpicture size, etc) as opposed to user input.

Comment: I would then really go with `subcaption`. You also might put your tikzpictures in a matrix node but that would not be as good in terms of caption placements.

Comment: Sounds like the `tabular` environment should do the job?

Comment: And what about the `groupplots` in `pgfplots`? I think that's what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While `tabularx` works, it's a bit overkill in this case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=7in, paperheight=5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

Examples
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5, yscale=.5]
\draw [<->,thick] (0,5) |- (5,0);
\draw [thick] (4,1) --(4,4);
\draw [thick, dashed] (4,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,4) -- (4,4);
\draw [fill] (4,1) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw [fill] (4,4) circle [radius=0.1];
\node at (2.5,2.5) {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{$A$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5, yscale=.5]
\draw [<->,thick] (0,5) |- (5,0);
\draw [thick, dashed] (1,1) to [out=90, in=280] (1,4) to [out=30, in=150] (2,3.5) to [out=30, in=200] (4,4) to [out=40, in=90] (5,3) to [out=270, in=90] (4,1) to [out=180, in=30] (1,1);
\node at (2.5,2.5) {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{$A$ is open.}
\end{minipage}

\medskip

\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5, yscale=.5]
\draw [<->,thick] (0,5) |- (5,0);
\draw [fill] (4,1) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw [fill] (2,1) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw [fill] (3,5) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw [fill] (1,3) circle [radius=0.1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{$A$ is not open.}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5, yscale=.5]
\draw [<->,thick] (0,2) |- (5,0);
\draw [ultra thick] (1,0) --(3,0) node [above] {$A$};
\draw [fill=white] (1,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw [fill=white] (3,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{$A$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ but open in $\mathbb{R}$.}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Note the `%` after the first `\end{minipage}` in each row, to avoid a spurious space. The `center` environment is just to remove indentations and to give some room after "Examples".

Use a different vertical space command instead of `\medskip`, if you prefer.

The `\label` commands are useless, as you don't number the captions. In any case, the strings should be different from each other.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've settled on uses the tabularx package.  I'm not sure why this allows captions when the tabular package gave me errors, but it does.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=7in, paperheight=5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

Examples

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X X }
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5, yscale=.5]
\draw [<->,thick] (0,5) |- (5,0);
\draw [thick] (4,1) --(4,4);
\draw [thick, dashed] (4,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,4) -- (4,4);
\draw [fill] (4,1) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw [fill] (4,4) circle [radius=0.1];
\node at (2.5,2.5) {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{$A$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.}
\label{tikz}

&

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5, yscale=.5]
\draw [<->,thick] (0,5) |- (5,0);
\draw [thick, dashed] (1,1) to [out=90, in=280] (1,4) to [out=30, in=150] (2,3.5) to [out=30, in=200] (4,4) to [out=40, in=90] (5,3) to [out=270, in=90] (4,1) to [out=180, in=30] (1,1);
\node at (2.5,2.5) {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{$A$ is open.}
\label{tikz}

\\

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5, yscale=.5]
\draw [<->,thick] (0,5) |- (5,0);
\draw [fill] (4,1) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw [fill] (2,1) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw [fill] (3,5) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw [fill] (1,3) circle [radius=0.1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{$A$ is not open.}
\label{tikz}

&

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5, yscale=.5]
\draw [<->,thick] (0,2) |- (5,0);
\draw [ultra thick] (1,0) --(3,0) node [above] {$A$};
\draw [fill=white] (1,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw [fill=white] (3,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{$A$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ but open in $\mathbb{R}$.}
\label{tikz}

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

And what it produces:

[image: 2x2 grid of tikzpictures with captions]

Although the captions don't seem "centered" below each tikzpicture, I'm satisfied.

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{>{\centering}X>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}` will do, but it's overkill.