# Table of 2x2 tikzpictures defined by my own macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tabularx

As a follow-up question from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158498) I am trying to find out how to arrange multiple tikspictures in a table, where my diagrams are defined by my own macros.

**Problem:** Showing the diagrams separately works, but they are not loaded in a table. Furthermore  I want the table to cover the textwidth of my document.

My question is similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100221/table-of-2x2-tikzpictures) with the difference that I'm trying to call a command which I defined in the preamble.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\clocks}[4]{
\begin{figure}[htb]
% \resizebox{#5 \textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ybar,
%  enlargelimits=0.25,
%  legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
%  anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
  ylabel={CPU clocks},
  symbolic x coords={one, two, three, four},
  xtick=data,
  nodes near coords,
  nodes near coords align={vertical},
]
\addplot coordinates {
(one, #1)
(two, #2)
(three, #3)
(four, #4)};
%\legend{one, two, three, four}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%}
\end{figure}
}


\begin{document}

\clocks{20}{50}{30}{70}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
A & B \\
\hline
C & D \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

%this table should be scaled to pagewidth!
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
\clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} & \clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} \\
\hline
\clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} & \clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `minipage`-s instead of a `tabularx`?! `\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}...\end{minipage}`

Comment: Because the errors are the same ("Not in outer par mode", "Undefined control sequence") as when using tabluarx.

At least
% first column
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} \\
\clocks{20}{50}{30}{70}
\end{minipage}
%second column
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} \\
\clocks{20}{50}{30}{70}
\end{minipage}

doesnt work

Comment: Why are you using `figure`? Is not enough to use only `tikzpicture`? Also, since you picture has a fixed width you will have problems to fit two of them in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a floating object (`figure`) inside a non-floating structure such as `tabularx`; remove the `figure` environment from the definition of `\clock`, and use an optional argument to control the width (I set the default value to `\linewidth`, but use whichever value you like better):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand{\clocks}[5][\linewidth]{%
% \resizebox{#5 \textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=#1,
  ybar,
%  enlargelimits=0.25,
%  legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
%  anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
  ylabel={CPU clocks},
  symbolic x coords={one, two, three, four},
  xtick=data,
  nodes near coords,
  nodes near coords align={vertical},
]
\addplot coordinates {
(one, #2)
(two, #3)
(three, #4)
(four, #5)};
%\legend{one, two, three, four}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
%}
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
\clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} & \clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} \\
\hline
\clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} & \clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Suppressing the lines from the table, and using `enlargelimits`, the result has a cleaner aspect:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand{\clocks}[5][\linewidth]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=#1,
  ybar,
  enlargelimits=0.25,
%  legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
%  anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
  ylabel={CPU clocks},
  symbolic x coords={one, two, three, four},
  xtick=data,
  nodes near coords,
  nodes near coords align={vertical},
]
\addplot coordinates {
(one, #2)
(two, #3)
(three, #4)
(four, #5)};
%\legend{one, two, three, four}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
%}
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
\clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} & \clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} \\
\clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} & \clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Outside floating objects you can provide a caption (requested in a comment) using `\captionof`, provided by the `caption` or `capt-of` packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand{\clocks}[5][\linewidth]{%
% \resizebox{#5 \textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=#1,
  ybar,
  enlargelimits=0.25,
%  legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
%  anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
  ylabel={CPU clocks},
  symbolic x coords={one, two, three, four},
  xtick=data,
  nodes near coords,
  nodes near coords align={vertical},
]
\addplot coordinates {
(one, #2)
(two, #3)
(three, #4)
(four, #5)};
%\legend{one, two, three, four}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
%}
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
\clocks{20}{50}{30}{70}
\captionof{figure}{a description for the first plot} 
& 
\clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} 
\captionof{figure}{a description for the second plot} \\
\clocks{20}{50}{30}{70}
\captionof{figure}{a description for the third plot} 
 & \clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} 
\captionof{figure}{a description for the fourth plot} \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks a little clearer if you remove the horizontal bars and the hlines from the tabularx. There is also a little problem with the 70 sticking up too high, which is easy to fix by changing font.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay yes; I added an option without rules and preventing the overlapping. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially the last output is what I desired. Only problem: if I don't use figure, how can I add captures to the individual diagrams?

Comment: @bogus please see the last example code in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**(!)** use `\noindent` before the tabular to avoid overfull warnings.

Use `\resizebox` instead of `figure`. Set up its value. I'm using `.45\textwidth`.

```
\newcommand{\clocks}[4]{
\resizebox{.45\textwidth}{!}{\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ybar,
  ylabel={CPU clocks},
  symbolic x coords={one, two, three, four},
  xtick=data,
  nodes near coords,
  nodes near coords align={vertical},
]
\addplot coordinates {
(one, #1)
(two, #2)
(three, #3)
(four, #4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
```

[image]

```
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
\clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} & \clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} \\
\hline
\clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} & \clocks{20}{50}{30}{70} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```